# Intel Graphics for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, 15.10

Exists intel graphics for ubuntu 15.10? If not, when is the launch date?

Comment: Intel's drivers are open source, and they come in Ubuntu already.

Comment: @dobey, isnt a duplicate, i dont need how install graphics, i just want to know if exists a graphics by intel corp for 15.10

Comment: There are no additional drivers to install. Ubuntu comes with the Intel drivers by default. They are open source and part of the upstream kernel and Xorg. There are no proprietary drivers to download and install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add oibaf ppa to get latest Intel drivers https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Answer (score 0):

There's no official launch date. It depends on Intel. You won't feel the difference anyway.

Comment: i tried to play steam games without drives, and is too lag man, i need the drivers....

Comment: its already installed @ArnaldoBadin

Comment: @StarOS so why steam games still with lag? on win its doesnt... For test i opened terraria and is sooo lag... my pc: 4gb ram, corei3, 2.1gh, intel graphics 1mb, this configs runs terraria easy... but in ubuntu 15.1 dont... i think "ooh the problem is the driver...."

Comment: it's not even the drivers.