# Minecraft on 15.10 Flickers

Tags: graphics, 15.10, intel, minecraft

This have never really been an issue for me in the past with previous versions of Ubuntu. However, now when I try to run Minecraft on my ASUS U56E I have a terrible screen flicker. I have already taken the time to look for my issue but I have not found a solution for 15.10. I have Intel graphics. 
Thanks For the Help!

Comment: I have found this info but I don't see how this helps for me https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-58760

Comment: I can provide any info that may be needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem was due to a lack in proper drivers for Ubuntu 15. I had to add them manually add them:

Running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

will add the latest/optimised Intel drivers.

More info can be found here:

[Intel Graphics for Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692006/intel-graphics-for-ubuntu-15-10)

Here:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

and here:

https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

**NOTE:** This as far as I know will work with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and later. It recommended you use it for 15.10 **ONLY**.