# Is the latest Ubuntu version, intel graphics compatible?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

I am using Ubuntu 15.10, and I update the second I have the ability. YouTube has screen tearing and certain games have flashing problems. I have read online that Ubuntu does not default support all aspects of the Intel graphics.

Does anyone know what I can download to enable support for this? drivers and such.

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

will add the latest/optimised Intel drivers.

More info can be found here:

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/692006/intel-graphics-for-ubuntu-15-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692006/intel-graphics-for-ubuntu-15-10/)

Here:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

and here:

https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

**NOTE:** This as far as I know will work with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and later. It recommended you use it for 15.10 **ONLY**.